# Infrastructure: Executing Remote Commands from a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

What's the best way to run commands on a remote windows machine from a rails app? I need to start/stop processes, and upload/download files.

Currently, I've thought of writing a ruby script or executable that resides on the machine that the rails app can talk to, but I've never done this before and would appreciate some thought on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I have never done this before and I don`t have a Windows machine to try but have you tried this:
`system('ls ~')`

As of the file upload/download - you can write something to a text file and then make an FTP client do actions based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a combination of local tools (ruby scripts, built-in system commands, etc...) and `#system` command. You can see a nice overview of how to execute shell commands from Ruby over at http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Using `#system` is recommended as it provides a boolean response depending on the outcome of the task.

```
system("ruby -e 'puts RUBY_VERSION'")
2.0.0
=> true

system("ruby -e 'raise StandardError'")
-e:1:in `<main>': StandardError (StandardError)
=> false
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this work on Windows as well? I'm assuming so. Are you suggesting have a script on the remote machine over using ssh?

Comment: The system command does work in the Windows environment. Rereading your question I realize I made an assumption that you would be running the Rails server on the Windows environment, but it looks like you're wanting to execute remote commands on the Windows box. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The rails app would be residing on a linux box, and would need to run commands on one or more windows servers.